# Pinescript - Syntax error at input 'else'

Tags: if-statement, pine-script

I am having an issue with pinescript. Never used it before and havent coded in years so im very rusty.
I would love an opinion of why I am getting the error on line 21, which is the only 'else if' line in the block.

```
//@version=4

tradeDirection = input(direction.up, "Trade Direction") // direction of the breakout (up or down)
breakoutPeriod = input(14, "Breakout Period") // number of bars to look back for the breakout
stopLoss = input(0.002, "Stop Loss") // stop loss in percentage of the trade value
takeProfit = input(0.004, "Take Profit") // take profit in percentage of the trade value
maxTrades = input(2, "Maximum Number of Trades") // maximum number of trades to have open at the same time
maxRisk = input(0.01, "Maximum Risk per Trade") // maximum risk per trade in percentage of the account value

// Next, we create a variable to track the highest or lowest price in the breakout period
breakoutPrice = tradeDirection == direction.up ? highest(high, breakoutPeriod) : lowest(low, breakoutPeriod)

// Then, we check if the current price has broken out of the breakout period and if we have not reached the maximum number of open trades
if (tradeDirection == direction.up and close > breakoutPrice and strategy.opentrades < maxTrades)

// If it has, we calculate the trade size based on the maximum risk per trade
    tradeSize = maxRisk / (stopLoss * close)
// And enter a long position with the calculated trade size
strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, tradeSize)

else if (tradeDirection == direction.down and close < breakoutPrice and strategy.opentrades < maxTrades)

// If it has, we calculate the trade size based on the maximum risk per trade
tradeSize = maxRisk / (stopLoss * close)
// And enter a short position with the calculated trade size
strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, tradeSize)


// Finally, we set our stop loss and take profit levels
strategy.exit("Stop Loss", "Long", stopLossType.percent, stopLoss)
strategy.exit("Take Profit", "Long", profitType.percent, takeProfit)

// We repeat the same process for the short position
strategy.exit("Stop Loss", "Short", stopLossType.percent, stopLoss)
strategy.exit("Take Profit", "Short", profitType.percent, takeProfit)
```

I've looked around at other versions to see if its just a version issue but nothing that gives me a reaosn why its erroring out.
I get the feeling its something before or within the else if statement.

Comment: Pine script is indentation sensitive. Indentation is used to create "blocks". Your indentation is inconsistent, almost non-existant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I retyped your script so it would compile and have no warnings or errors. One problem was the indentation was missing on the `if` and `else`. Another problem was the `direction.up` variable was missing. It is not allowed to have a `.` in a variable name. Another problem was that `strategy("breakout strat")` was missing, so I added it. The logic in the code I typed is probably wrong, but there are no errors.

```
//@version=4
strategy("breakout strat")

tradeDirection = input(true, "Trade Direction") // direction of the breakout (up=true or down=false)
breakoutPeriod = input(14, "Breakout Period") // number of bars to look back for the breakout
stopLoss = input(0.002, "Stop Loss") // stop loss in percentage of the trade value
takeProfit = input(0.004, "Take Profit") // take profit in percentage of the trade value
maxTrades = input(2, "Maximum Number of Trades") // maximum number of trades to have open at the same time
maxRisk = input(0.01, "Maximum Risk per Trade") // maximum risk per trade in percentage of the account value

// Next, we create a variable to track the highest or lowest price in the breakout period
breakoutPrice = tradeDirection == true ? highest(high, breakoutPeriod) : lowest(low, breakoutPeriod)

// Then, we check if the current price has broken out of the breakout period and if we have not reached the maximum number of open trades
if (tradeDirection == true and close > breakoutPrice and strategy.opentrades < maxTrades)
    // If it has, we calculate the trade size based on the maximum risk per trade
    tradeSize = maxRisk / (stopLoss * close)
    // And enter a long position with the calculated trade size
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, tradeSize)

else if (tradeDirection == false and close < breakoutPrice and strategy.opentrades < maxTrades)
    // If it has, we calculate the trade size based on the maximum risk per trade
    tradeSize = maxRisk / (stopLoss * close)
    // And enter a short position with the calculated trade size
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, tradeSize)


// Finally, we set our stop loss and take profit levels
strategy.exit("Stop Loss", "Long", loss=stopLoss)
strategy.exit("Take Profit", "Long", loss=takeProfit)

// We repeat the same process for the short position
strategy.exit("Stop Loss", "Short", loss=stopLoss)
strategy.exit("Take Profit", "Short", loss=takeProfit)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Marcus. Wasnt expecting it to be done for me and so quickly. Very much appreciated. You nailed it in one... works perfect.. no errors at all.

Answer (score 0):

Put an indentation on line 21 to get rid of this error :

```
if .....
----> First block
else if
----> Other block
```

In your code other indentations are missing, and other error are present (direction.up doesn't exist for example... but you should ask another question for another error)